# Position of a jquery UI dialog from top of DIV

Tags: jquery-ui, dialog, position

I use a jQuery UI 1.10.2 to display a dialog within a DIV. This container div has a dynamic ajax content.

Currently i center the dialog like this:

```
$( "#mydialog" ).dialog({position: my: "center center", at: "center center", of: "#mycontainer"}});
```

It works great, but if the container has a large height users need to scroll to see the dialog, so i would like to center my dialog horizontally, and display it at 75px from the top of the container.

If i understand correctly this "position" utility, according to [jquery UI documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-position) we should be able to do this:

```
$( "#mydialog" ).dialog({position: my: "center center", at: "center top+75", of: "#mycontainer"}});
```

However it does not work, the dialog is stuck at the top of the container. Though if i use "top+25%" it works , see [this js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/donio/rAhPJ/1/). Can i use a margin-top in pixels using "position" jquery utility for this dialog?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Finally i found out what's wrong: because of the first argument 'center center'  the height of the dialog was removing the margin-top.

Here is the solution:

```
$( "#mydialog" ).dialog({ my: "center top", at: "center top+75", of: "#mycontainer"})
```

I updated the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rAhPJ/2/).